# Existencia de un d-redígito múltiplo de un número N

Tags: python, algoritmos, matemáticas, eficiencia

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Dado un dígito d>0, y un número N, debo determinar la longitud del menor d-redígito múltiplo de N.

Un número natural x es un d-redígito si el número x está compuesto por sólo d's. 
Ejemplo: 11111 es un 1-redígito.

Puede que no exista un d-redígito que sea múltiplo de N.

Sé como resolver el problema cuando sé que existe este d-redígito que es múltiplo de N. No obstante, no sé cómo determinar si este d-redígito múltiplo de N existe.

El lenguaje de programación sobre el que se implemente la solución no es relevante. Sin embargo, he intentado lo siguiente en Python:

```py
def proyect_a(n:int, d:int):
    if n == 0 or d == 0:
        return ''
    i = 1
    red = d
    while i < 11 and red%n != 0:
        red = 10*red + d
        i+=1
    if i < 11:
        return len(str(red))
    else:
        return '*'
```

Como se puede ver, el programa es una solución de fuerza bruta, pues no calcula en todos los casos el menor d-redígito múltiplo de N, dado que el ciclo se realiza como máximo 10 veces. Lo anterior es debido a que no sé cómo verificar si este d-redígito múltiplo de N existe.

Comment: Pues ideas si, pero ¿en qué lenguaje de programación? ¿qué has intentado? Por favor revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: El lenguaje de programación realmente no importa, puede ser pseudo código, preferiblemente GCL.